# vba excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

1.I'm trying to write a VBA script to create a user form in Excel to search in a database when I write the search button code it gave me an error in the 5th line ( If Trim(Data.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(txtsearch.Text) And i = isearch Then )

Appreciate if anyone have a solution for that.

2.Code :

```
        Private Sub Comsear_Click()

        Dim isearch As Long, i As Long
        isearch = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        For i = 10 To isearch

        If Trim(Data.Cells(i, 1)) <> Trim(txtsearch.Text) And i = isearch Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid data")
        txtsearch.Text = ""
        txtsearch.SetFocus
        End If

        If Trim(Data.Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(txtsearch.Text) Then
        Texgl.Text = Data.Cells(i, 1)
        Texitem.Text = Data.Cells(i, 2)
        Texid.Text = Data.Cells(i, 3)
        Texgender.Text = Data.Cells(i, 4)
        Texb5.Text = Data.Cells(i, 5)
        Texb4.Text = Data.Cells(i, 6)
        Texpc.Text = Data.Cells(i, 7)
        Texpcid.Text = Data.Cells(i, 8)

        Exit For
        End If
        Next i

        End Sub
```

Comment: `Data` is not `Set` (or is it the codename of a worksheet?). What is the error message?

Comment: `Trim( Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1))` Maybe?

Comment: Error: Run-time'424': Object required   -   the error in the 5th line

Comment: Unless the sheet Data is renamed equally in VBA (Data(Data) instead of Data(Sheet3) for example, you can see this under Microsoft Excel Objects in VBA window) you cannot just say "Data", either declare a worksheet variable Dim Data as Worksheet and set it like it  Set Data= Sheets("Data") (which is the best) or rename your object

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` and declaring all your variables may help debug the problem.